# Int cannot be converted to boolean?? converting code from C to Java

Tags: java, c, printing, int, boolean

I have a code that I am converting into Java, Im new to programming but I already have done some work on both PL, although I do not understand why I get this error

The original C code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main () {
    int i, j, k;
    for (i=1; i<=59; i++) {
        k = 1;
        for (j=2; j<i; j++)
            if (i % (j*j) == 0) k = 0;
        if (k) printf ("%d\n", i);
    }
    printf("%d",i);
    getch();
}
```

My converted Java code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class squarefree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j,k;
        for(i=1; i<60; i++){
            k=1;
            for(j=2; j<i; j++){
                if(i % (j*j) == 0) 
                    k=0;
                if(k) System.out.println(i);
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain? Thanks guys :)

Comment: Added my comment as answer instead with some additional details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 ways to fix this:

1) Use `if (k != 0)`, since in java an `int` is an `int` and a `boolean` is its own type.

2) Having said that, why not change `k` to a boolean value? You're using it for a boolean check, and it only changes from 0 to 1, so if you actually use the boolean value it'll be much easier to read.

eg:

```
boolean k = true;

// your code here
    // your ifstatement to change k
    k = false;

// print code
if (k) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

What don't you understand about the error message? `if(k)` doesn't make any sense in java-land. Did you mean to write `if(k != 0)` in order to test for a non-zero value?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike in C, `int` aren't implicitly converted in `boolean` in Java.

You just have to write `if( k != 0 )` :)

Answer (score 2):

In `C` you can compare an `int` as a `boolean` and any non-zero value is considered TRUE. In Java, that is not the case. This

```
if(k) System.out.println(i);
```

should be something like

```
if(k != 0) System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java a boolean is either true or false. In C, int stands in for a boolean type with true being non-zero and false being zero. So what you're looking for is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i, j;
    boolean k;

    for(i=1; i<60; i++){
        k=true;
        for(j=2; j<i; j++){
            if(i % (j*j) == 0) 
                k=false;
        }
        if(k) System.out.println(i);
    }
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the effort guys, I got it to run, but it dosen't seem to produce the same result as my C program does for some reason. I'll try to find a way though